# Maven dependency management being ignored at test time (works at runtime)

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

I have two dependencies which point to a conflicting version of `javax.validation:validation-api`. To resolve this, I added a `dependencyManagement` section with the latest version of the `validation-api`.

While this causes the app to build correct, and the app works at runtime, during tests, the build breaks at a line in which the validation api is referenced (via a `@Valid` annotation).

The conflicting dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0-beta1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've added the following `dependencyManagement`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This works at runtime and compile time, but fails in tests where I refer `@Valid`.

Would greatly appreciate any help, as this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

A possible troubleshooting path is on the scope (`provided`) defined for `gwt-user`, which is the only library bringing in `validation-api` applying the dependencies management above.

Running the following first omitting `dropwizard-core`

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=javax.validation
```

The output would be:

```
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.8.0-beta1:provided  
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile  
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:provided
```

Taking hence the desired **1.1.0.Final** version instead of the transitive **1.0.0.GA** one.
(Note the scopes above, the last token per dependency entry, they should all be on `provided` because its root, `gwt-user` is on `provided` scope. However, `validation-api` is on `compile` because of the dependency management entry).

While omitting `gwt-user` the output would be:

```
[INFO] com.sample:sample2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO]    \- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO]       \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO]          \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
```

Hence, indeed, both would bring it in, but the first was defined as `provided` scope while the second as default (`compile`) scope.

Moreover, the dependency management for `validation-api` has been defined for default (`compile`) scope, impacting how Maven is bringing it in via `gwt-user` (listed above, as `compile`, even though `gwt-user` is `provided` and all of its transitive dependencies would also be on `provided`, unless defined differently by dependencies management, like in this case).

Provided dependencies, per [official Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) are

> available on the compilation and test classpath

Hence you are having during compilation and test two libraries in conjuction, `validation-api` and `gwt-user`, which would then have different coupling at runtime (`gwt-user` is expected to be *provided* by the runtime container).

If `gwt-user` must be in `provided` scope, I would suggest to adopt a finer governance and exclude `validation-api` directly from `gwt-user`. As such, `validation-api` will be brought in from `dropwizard-core` with the version required by the dependencies management.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0-beta1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Update**
From your comment below, you are also using the following as part of your dependencies management:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0-beta1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which is then also specifying the following in its dependencies management:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    <!-- Note: use classifier=sources rather than type=java-sources so they're added to the classpath -->
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

While you managed to override the first, you didn't override the second and indeed it is still added to the classpath (check dependency tree output above, the **1.0.0.GA** sources are still brought in, in provided scope. That's a further difference between compiler/test and runtime. At runtime, you don't have it as part of your classpath.

I would hence suggest to also add to your dependencies management its **1.1.0.Final** version as overriden, so that it would be coherent with the first one.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're thinking along the right lines. However, I've already tried exclusions and just tried them again - the error doesn't go away. It continues to appear in tests, while runtime continues to work. So it doesn't go away in tests.

Comment: This is the output of running dependency tree: `[INFO] com.myproject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO]       \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile`

Comment: to have something more coherent, you could try to apply scope provided to the dependencyManagement entry, then remove the esplicit exclusion you just added. Then you may have the same error at runtime: while this is not nice at first, it could then help further towards the right solution.

Comment: Yep, adding that gives a runtime error as well. One more thing, in my dependencyManagement, I have the following entry: `<dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0-beta1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>`

Comment: @ClickUpvote check my update, I found a further important difference which may help you out

Comment: I've now added the following to my dependencyManagement: `<dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                <classifier>sources</classifier>
            </dependency>`. However, it still fails at test time. Am I overriding it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to excluded the dependency from one or another like this :

```
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
          <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.2</version>
       </dependency>

     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.0-beta1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion> 
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions> 
    </dependenc
```

Comment: Same issue, doesn't work. Does work at runtime, but tests fail.